# python - how to do list in list

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
country=['Uruguay', 'Mexico', 'Uruguay', 'France', 'Mexico']
```

I have to count the occurrence of element in list. This is my output.

```
['Uruguay', 2, 'Mexico', 2, 'France', 1]
```

But how to do the list in list like below?

```
[['Uruguay', 2], ['Mexico', 2], ['France', 1]]
```

Comment: If the final order doesn't matter: `[[i, country.count(i)] for i in set(country)]`

Comment: `collections.Counter(country)`

Comment: just do `temp.append([i, count])` instead of doing `temp2.append(i); temp2.append(count)` in order to make your code work

Answer (score 0):

You can implement with `list comprehension`.

```
In [5]: print [[i,country.count(i)] for i in set(country)]
Out[5]: [['Mexico', 2], ['France', 1], ['Uruguay', 2]]
```

Also with `collections.Counter`,

```
from collections import Counter
result = map(list,Counter(country).items())
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and [List Comprehensions](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk)

```
>>> country = ['Uruguay', 'Mexico', 'Uruguay', 'France', 'Mexico']
>>> [[i, j] for i, j in collections.Counter(country).items()]
[['Mexico', 2], ['France', 1], ['Uruguay', 2]]
```

Comment: What's the point of that list comprehension?

Comment: The OP want a list of list as his result. @DanielRoseman

Comment: @DanielRoseman list of what? could show me please? the result should be a list of list?

Comment: @vovaminiof that give your a list of tuple, not a list of list my friend.

Comment: why would need exactly list? Anyhow, it can be also done like following: map(list, collections.Counter(country).items())

Comment: I am not a big fun of list myself. The OP said clearly he want a list of list. So I don't want to give an apple when a banana is needed. @vovaminiof